# How do I rotate my geometry?

Tags: modeling

I was following the Blender Guru tutorial for adding sprinkles onto the icing.

However, When I try to do what he did at 32:59, I encountered this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your mirror modifier has two dimensions checked, while his has only one checked (I'm guessing **Y**).

Comment: ahh that was so careless of me, thanks for the help!